# How to change specific button value after ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, ajaxform

I have a list if items and on each item I have button. When I click on that button I make server call and after that call I need to change button text. So I write this function to ajaxify call:

```
$('.form').ajaxForm({
            beforeSubmit: function () {                
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $('.itemHoverBox').attr('value', 'Confirmed');
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {           
            }
        });
```

This is action button:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Confirm", "Products", new { productId = @t.ProductId }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class="form"}))
{
<input style="width: 60px;" class="itemHoverBox button white" type="submit" value="Confirm" />
}
```

But this change all `itemHoverBox` on the page, and what I am trying is just to change button that I clicked. Like when you click favorite question star here on stackoverflow.
My action method returns void for now:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void CollectTicket(int ticketId)
        {
            ...           
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could capture the form in a closure:

```
$('.form').each(function() {
    var form = $(this);
    form.ajaxForm({
        success: function (result) {
            form.find('.itemHoverBox').attr('value', 'Confirmed');
        }
    });
});
```

or even cleaner, using the `context` parameter:

```
$('.form').each(function() {
    var form = $(this);
    form.ajaxForm({
        context: form,
        success: function (result) {
            // Here this will equal to the context object we specified
            this.find('.itemHoverBox').attr('value', 'Confirmed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This code would still change all buttons within the form with the class name 'itemHoverBox' to 'Confirmed', which is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @ChrisGessler, no, it won't. Because I have the following selector in the success callback: `form.find('.itemHoverBox')` which is not at all the same as `$('.itemHoverBox')`. My selector will find all **child elements** of the form with the `itemHoverBox` class whereas the second will simply select all elements in the DOM with this class.

Comment: Correct, all "within the form".  If one wants to change just one button, it's better to use the ID of the element. Personally, I wouldn't use jQuery at all to do this.  document.getElementById() is much faster.

Comment: @ChrisGessler, but what if you have multiple dynamic forms into a table for example, each with its own submit button? Would you give each submit button a different id? Would you then repeat the same code (`.ajaxForm`) for each id that you have?

Comment: That's what I want to ask. I have thousands item's and I don't want to set each item id. This solution works. Thanks

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - if you have multiple dynamic forms and a single button for each form, then use "input[type='submit']" rather than the class name and your form closure.

Comment: yeah, but if you use `input[type='submit']` that would select all submit buttons in the entire DOM which is what the OP doesn't want. He wants to select the submit button of the form that was submitted using an AJAX call.

Comment: It's possible. Could you please explain the point that I am missing? Or even better, answer the question that the OP is asking. In your answer you are suggesting to apply unique ids to each submit buttons which the OP explicitly stated that he doesn't want.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - combine your capture code with "input[type='submit']" and stop using a generic class name that could appear anywhere, even inside the same form multiple times.

Comment: You mean like: `form.find('input[type="submit"]')` or even shorter `form.find(':submit')`? That would indeed work if you have a single submit button inside each form.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - yes. I'm supporting your answer because I didn't know there was MULTIPLE forms on the page.  But I think selecting the INPUT button is better practice because another developer may come along and add some other element and use the generic class name.